# How can I use the Translator service outside of a controller in Symfony 3?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form type:

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Form/ProductType.php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class ProductType extends AbstractType
{

    private $translator;

    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Product',
        ));
    }
}
```

As you see I am already attempting to set up my form type to inject the translator. In my services I have:

```
parameters:
#    parameter_name: value

services:
    app.form.product:
        class: AppBundle\Form\ProductType
        arguments: ["@translator"]
```

But am receiving the following error:

> ```
> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Form\ProductType::__construct() must implement interface
> ```
>
> Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface, none given, called
>   in
>   /path/to/symfony/bundle/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php
>   on line 85 and defined....

Can someone tell me what gives? I am pretty sure the service type is wrong but cant find the one I need to save my life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in the service definition of your form that you have correctly tag the service as a form.type as described [here in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service).

In according with the [news announcement](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-improvements-for-the-translation-component), from the version 2.6 the translator component is defined as service like `translator.default`.

As Example, you should have something like:

```
services:
    app.form.product:
        class: AppBundle\Form\ProductType
        arguments: ["@translator.default"]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

hope this help

Comment: It was the lack of the "tags" argument that was keeping it from working. Also I had to "use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator;" instead of TranslatorInterface like in my code above. Thanks a bundle. Also the use of the console command: "bin/console debug:container" helps to find out which services are inject-able and helps find which "use" statements to use.